# How to send jwt in xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jwt

I can store the jwt token in local storage, but i don't know how to send it as a bearer token back to my restful api endpoint and i just can't find this information anywhere. How could i do that using only xmlhttprequest?

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtoken);`

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by using `setRequestHeader()` function. This function is using to set the value of an HTTP request header. When using `setRequestHeader()`, you must call it after calling open(), but before calling `send()`. If this method is called several times with the same header, the values are merged into one single request header.

```
function initXMLHttpRequest(method, url, jwtoken){
    let xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpRequest.open(method, url);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtoken);
    return xmlHttpRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible.

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("jwtoken"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Set authorization header in your xmlhttprequest.

```
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
```